# Write pyspark stderr from console to log file in specific directory

Tags: logging, pyspark

I am submitting a pyspark program in client mode (local) using spark2-submit test.py

I would like to write all the STDERR generated to a log file to a directory that I want to.

Is there a way to do that.

I know that the below will write stderr to a text file in the same direcotry as program

```
spark2-submit something.py > results.txt 2>&1
```

But is there a way to write it to specific log directory that I have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just give the full path to the log_file like below

```
spark-submit something.py >> /path/to/directory/and/log_file_name 2>&1
```